# How to check if the user is a registered user so that he can log in using ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, authentication

I am trying to enable a user to login only if he is registered. I have a registration page, where I have written a web service to successfully register the user, then the user tries to login. So basically I need to write a web service to POST login details and check if the user is registered- if yes then direct to home page else show error. I managed to write code for posting the data which is as follows:
**LoginButton action:**

```
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: UIButton) { 
if userNameTextField.isValidEmail(userNameTextField.text!)
        {
            let userName = userNameTextField.text
            let password = passwordTextField.text

            //Data dictionary to save user data
            let parameterDictionary:[String : String] = [
                "first_name": userName!,
                "password": password!]

            let additionalUrlString = "users/register"

            //Calling postDataRequest to send data to the web service and wait for response
            CommonFunctions.sharedInstance.postdataRequest(parameterDictionary, accessToken: "", urlStr: additionalUrlString, Block: {
                (AnyObject) -> Void in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    if (AnyObject.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)){
                        if(AnyObject["status"] as! NSObject == 200) /*Code:200 for success in the api*/{
                            self.view.makeToast("Login Successfully")

                            let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
                            dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomePageViewController") as! HomePageViewController
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
                            }
                        }else{
                            print("Login Unsuccessful")
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                //  let mwsg: String = AnyObject["message"]! as! String
                                self.view.makeToast(AnyObject["message"]! as! String)
                            })
                        }
                    }else{
                        print("No server response")
                    }
                })
            })
        } else {
            userNameTextField.showAlertDialog("Invalid email ID", viewController: self)
        }
    }
```

**PostDataRequest:**

```
func postdataRequest(parameter: Dictionary<String, String>, accessToken: String, urlStr: String, Block block: completionBlockType){
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: baseURL + urlStr)! //Create url of the api
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url) //create request object to be sent
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    setBodyContent(parameter, request: request) //Convert data dictionary to string to be sent to the server
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
  //            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  //                IJProgressView.shared.hideProgressView()
  //            })
         let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
         print("Body: \(strData)!") //Displays user data sent back by the server after saving
        let datastring = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
        block(datastring)
  })


    task.resume()
}
```

Can someone help me to check if the user is registered or not

Comment: I think you need to write a `GET` service as you are requesting details from the server and `GET` is what you use to authenticate usually. Not `POST`. There will be some particular parameter which you should check in the JSON data received. Paste the JSON data AND the code you tried to authenticate here . If you still run into problems, we'll try helping you out.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 But the project i am working on needs data to be posted. The api says POST.

Comment: Yes but to authenticate you need to use GET. You may use POST for your other work. :)